# Intersection of closed connected subsets is connected

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let X be a compact Hausdorff space.

(a) Suppose that $\mathcal{C} \,$ is a nonempty collection of closed connected
sub-sets that is simply ordered by inclusion. Prove that $ ∩\big\{ \ { C : C ∈ \mathcal{C} \, } \big \}$
is connected.

(b) Let B be a filter base in $X$ consisting of closed connected subsets
of $X$. Show that the intersection of members of B is a closed
connected set.

Here I do not know how to use that they are not countable and that is simply ordered by inclusion. Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understtod "simply ordered" as "linearly ordered". Then Claim a is a corollary of Claim b, and the latter follows from the next proposition from Engelking’s “General topology”

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]